# How do I make ErrorDialog default icon bigger?

Tags: java, swt, jface

I'm trying to improve the UI of my GUI dialog that pops up in case of an error. I however can't seems to resize the default error icon that appears on the left of the GUI. See image below.
[image: Original size of icon in attached image]

I tried doing that with the code below.

```
@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
private void displayStatusDialog(IStatus s)
{
    checkNotNull(s);
    Display.getDefault().syncExec( () ->
    {
        ErrorDialogWithBigIcon window = new ErrorDialogWithBigIcon(
            Display.getDefault().getActiveShell(),
            AppMessages.msg("SEMANTIC_ISSUES_TITLE"), "", s, 0); 

        window.openError(Display.getDefault().getActiveShell(),
            AppMessages.msg("SEMANTIC_ISSUES_TITLE"),null, s); 
        window.setDefaultImage(window.getImage());
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window default image is nothing to do with the error image.

You need to extend the `ErrorDialog` class and override the `getImage` method, something like:

```
@Override
protected Image getImage() {
   Image image = super.getImage();

   ... your resize code here

   return image;
}
```

You would use it with something like:

```
ErrorDialogWithBigIcon test = 
   new ErrorDialogWithBigIcon(shell, "Title", "Message", status, 
          IStatus.OK | IStatus.INFO | IStatus.WARNING | IStatus.ERROR);
test.open();
```

Comment: This does not work
        `public class ErrorDialogWithBigIcon extends ErrorDialog
{
    public ErrorDialogWithBigIcon(Shell parentShell, 
        String dialogTitle, String message, 
        IStatus status, int displayMask)
    { super(parentShell, dialogTitle, message, status, displayMask);   }
    
    @Override
    protected Image getImage() 
    {
        Image image = super.getImage();
        Image bigger = new Image(Display.getCurrent(), image.getImageData().scaledTo(100, 100));
        return  bigger;
    }
}`

Comment: Your code works for me. Edit your question and show us how you are using this.

Comment: I did not know how to get the wizard window without using the openError method. Maybe it has something to do with me putting the displayMask to 0.

Comment: `openError` is a static method which doesn't use the new class. You must use `open` method. You must also specify a non-zero display mask - see my example in the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449. It works. You are one of the most knowledgeable coder I have come across.